# Azure search Language analyzers and diacritics

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, diacritics

We're setting up an azure search index, and we're using language analyzers, which seem to work great. (splitting words, adding stems etc.) However, we have an issue with diacritics (accents).

In Dutch, a `patient` is written as `patiënt`. When adding text containing `patiënt` to a a field set to `microsoft.nl`, it also adds a token for `patient`. So if I search for `patient` (without the ë), it also finds this document.

The problem arises when the situation is reversed. If someone types `patient` in a document (because he is to lazy to add the ë), the tokenizer doesn't add a patiënt token. When someone now searches for patiënt, the document is not found.

What is the proper solution for this? I would like for it not to matter if I add the diacritics in the search text or not. I've been looking at custom analyzers to remove diacritics altogether, but they don't seem to play nice with language analyzers

To clarify: I'm looking for a solution for all cases with diacritics, not only for this specific word

current field definition:

```
{
    "name": "Contents_nlnl",
    "type": "Edm.String",
    "facetable": false,
    "filterable": false,
    "key": false,
    "retrievable": false,
    "searchable": true,
    "sortable": false,
    "analyzer": "nl.microsoft",
    "indexAnalyzer": null,
    "searchAnalyzer": null,
    "synonymMaps": [],
    "fields": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a synonym map with explicit mapping
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms#explicit-mapping
See example below

```
{
    "name": "patient",
    "format": "solr",
    "synonyms": "patient=> patiënt"
}
```

Comment: Yeah this would only solve this one specific case, not all cases with diacritics. I've updated my question to clarify